Transposing only comma separated values from an array in google sheet
I have a database with references in column V. Some cells have single value, like 0001, others have several comma separated values, like 0001, 0002, 0003. I am trying to retrieve this data to a single column, but can not deal with transpose.
Here's the formula which working but not transposing data:
=ARRAYFORMULA(SPLIT(QUERY(ShotLISTbase!A:V, "SELECT V WHERE A = '"&ShotLIST_Print!J1&"' AND V is not null"), ", "))

This formula returns comma separated data in different columns:

I need to put all results in first column, transposing comma separated values.
Thank you in advance.
I've tried IF condition, but didn't achieve wanted result:
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(IF(SEARCH(",", QUERY(ShotLISTbase!A:V, "SELECT V WHERE A = '"&ShotLIST_Print!J1&"' AND V is not null"))>1,TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(QUERY(ShotLISTbase!A:V, "SELECT V WHERE A = '"&ShotLIST_Print!J1&"' AND V is not null"), ", "))),SPLIT(QUERY(ShotLISTbase!A:V, "SELECT V WHERE A = '"&ShotLIST_Print!J1&"' AND V is not null"), ", ")))


Can you include a sample input? I can only assume that your input is already in one column? The only problem is that some rows(in this case, cells since there is only one column) have multiple entries separated by commas. Did I understand your issue correcrly?

Have you tried using FLATTEN and then QUERY?
=QUERY(FLATTEN(ARRAYFORMULA(SPLIT(,","))),"SELECT Col1 WHERE Col1 IS NOT NULL")

@PatrickdC yes, I've started with FLATTEN then removed it, I didn't notice it influence result here.

Use tocol(), like this:
=tocol(filter(split(ShotLISTbase!V1:V, ", "), ShotLISTbase!A1:A = ShotLIST_Print!J1), 3)

See tocol().

Great thank you! That is exactly what I was looking for.
